# how to use background-size to fill whole div without breaking with background-image?

Tags: html, css

At normal resolutions it doesn't break:

[image]

Now in smaller resolution breaks:

[image]

My css code:

```
tfoot {
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    max-width: 100%;
    justify-content: right;
    background-image: url(https://dv.bamboostock.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/GABRIEL_png.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: left;
    margin-top: 130px;
    place-items: right;
}
```

My css code in breakpoint:

@media (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 912px) {

```
tfoot {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    background-size: contain;
    margin-top: 80px;
    justify-items: end;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Build the background using gradients and you won't have such issue:

```css
.box {
  height: 300px;
  border:2px solid red;
  background:
   linear-gradient(#fff 50%,#0000 0),
   radial-gradient(circle closest-side,#0000 69%,#000 71%) 50%/40px 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply! but how do i get all the background with this style? since it only imposes half the value, would I stop using the background-image?

Comment: @Weverton I don't understand your question